# Using print to access individual cells of pandas dataframe after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

After using groupby on one column of say 9 column data set,how can I access individual cells in a print statement. All examples show output from ipython. I need to format data for other software. Code that I have included does not work.

> 800200.2986     3859676.9971      WELL01              IZHA        107.000      10100.0000     6483.3506      6483.0552      -6376.0552        NIN
>   800200.2986     3859676.9971      WELL01              KEY B       107.000      10100.0000     6664.8892      6664.5864      -6557.5864        NIN
>   800200.2986     3859676.9971      WELL01              SIMS        107.000      10100.0000     2120.7332      2120.7112      -2013.7112        NIN2
>   800200.2986     3859676.9971      WELL01              BOT0          107.000      10100.0000     8426.7568      8426.3613      -8319.3613        NIN
>   800200.2986     3859676.9971      WELL01              BOT0-2A       107.000      10100.0000     8476.9834      8476.5830      -8369.5830        NIN

```
wls= pd.read_fwf(cmdl.datafilename,skiprows=10,colspecs= colwidths,names=colnames)
tpgrp = wls.groupby('Top')
tpgrpdict= dict(list(tpgrp))
tp0= tpgrp.get_group('BOT0')
#print tp0,tp0.count()
print tp0[['X','Y','TVDSS','Well']]
for t in tp0:
    for i in range(len(t)):
        print t[i],tp0[tp0[]['X']
```

Comment: Have you had a look at and tried the methods here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tpgrp = wls.groupby('Top')
tpgrpdict= dict(list(tpgrp))
tp0= tpgrp.get_group('BOT0')
```

The dataframe you posted has no column named 'Top', nor a row named 'BOT0'.

`groupby()` returns a [DataFrameGroupBy](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#groupby) object, which has a `groups` attribute, which is a dictionary where the group names are the keys, and each value is an array containing the names of the rows for that group.  You can step through the keys and convert each group name into a dataframe with `get_group()`.

Then, you can access individual cells with `.loc[]`, for example:

```
df.loc['row_name', 'column_name']
```

Or, you can use `.iloc[]`, for example:

```
df.iloc[0, -1]    #row 0, last cell in row
```

Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(
{
    'A' : ['x', 'y', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'x'],
    'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
    'C' : np.random.randn(8), 
    'D' : np.random.randn(8)
}
)

print df
```

---

```
       A      B         C         D
0  x    one -0.495361  0.349394
1  y    one -0.650411 -0.015773
2  x    two  1.249771  0.688563
3  y  three  0.538023 -1.171365
4  x    two -0.251789 -1.919394
5  y    two -1.308169  1.140029
6  x    one -0.404656  0.196439
7  x  three  1.318467 -0.294299
```

---

```
group_by_obj = df.groupby('A')
group_dict = group_by_obj.groups

print group_dict
```

---

```
{'y': [1L, 3L, 5L], 'x': [0L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 7L]}  #The lists contain row numbers
```

---

```
for group_name in group_dict.keys():
    new_df = group_by_obj.get_group(group_name)
    print new_df
    print '.' * 20

    print new_df.loc[:,'A':'C']  #extract all rows(:), and columns A through C
    print new_df.iloc[0, -1]  #row=0, col=-1
    print '*' * 20
```

---

```
   A      B         C         D
1  y    one -0.650411 -0.015773
3  y  three  0.538023 -1.171365
5  y    two -1.308169  1.140029
....................
   A      B         C
1  y    one -0.650411
3  y  three  0.538023
5  y    two -1.308169
-0.0157729776716
********************
   A      B         C         D
0  x    one -0.495361  0.349394
2  x    two  1.249771  0.688563
4  x    two -0.251789 -1.919394
6  x    one -0.404656  0.196439
7  x  three  1.318467 -0.294299
....................
   A      B         C
0  x    one -0.495361
2  x    two  1.249771
4  x    two -0.251789
6  x    one -0.404656
7  x  three  1.318467
0.349393627206
********************
```

Comment: Sorry for not including the col names. Thank you very much for the response. Exactly what I was looking for.